# Compiler bug with void[n] arrays?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, void, unsafe

I'm working on some unsafe C# code that includes a lot of declarations similar to:

```
void* voidPointer = stackalloc void[bufferSize];
```

Building this code, I'm getting an error "Error 1   Keyword 'void' cannot be used in this context   " on each line like this.

Weirdly, if I cut and paste back the `[bufferSize]` portion of the declaration into the same place and save, the compiler stops complaining.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 2

Anybody know what is up with this?

Comment: `void*` is a pointer to objects of unknown size. You can’t allocate `bufferSize` objects of unknown size. Try `stackalloc byte[bufferSize]`… maybe.

Comment: @usr: Oh, it’s right, then? Phew! I will make it an answer; thank you. =)

Comment: @minitech your answer seems correct, but I'm confused with that copy/paste part. how could that happen?

Comment: Oh no. Your answer has no problems. I meant the question: `Weirdly, if I cut and paste back the [bufferSize] portion of the declaration into the same place and save, the compiler stops complaining.`

Comment: @Alireza: Ah, yep! I was also confused about that, hence not answering initially. I suppose we’ll just have to wait and see…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void*` is a pointer to objects of unknown size. You can’t allocate `bufferSize` objects of unknown size. Try `(byte*)(stackalloc byte[bufferSize])` instead.

Comment: @usr: Thanks for the edit! Sorry to ask, but what does `stackalloc` usually return? I can’t find it in the documentation. It seems like it ought to be a `byte*` already, logically.

Comment: @minitech stackalloc returns a pointer to a type that is equal to the array elements' type

Comment: After digging into the file in question, it appears that it was code generated by some (possibly broken) tool.  Fortunately, I can junk it.